# Which IPC signals are mapped by default to the keyboard on a macbook?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, unix

Which of the posix [IPC signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) are mapped by default to keyboard combinations on MacOS on a macbook keyboard?

The MacOS manual [lists the signals](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/signal.3.html), but not keybindings.

For instance these appear to be widely known:

- `ctrl-c` -> SIGINT
- `ctrl-t` -> SIGINFO
- `ctrl-z` -> SIGTSTP

But I've not found definitive documentation for a full list.

An equivalent question for ubuntu can be seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436306/what-are-the-interrupts-that-user-can-invoke-in-terminal)

Comment: Which practical problem are you trying to solve here? And what did you find in the man page of the shell you are using?

Comment: Ultimately I'm hoping to identify a key-mapped signal that's available across most platforms (BSDs, other unix, Windows) to be used to trigger custom functionality in a command line executable. I'm ok with bending the intention of the signal. `ctrl-c` is already utilized. `ctrl-t` is good but not available on non-bsd platforms. `ctrl-z` may be the best, but I wanted to review the exhaustive list.

Comment: In terms of terminal manual, the best I can find is
`% stty -a ... cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V; min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;` but which signals these map to isn't fully clear

Comment: The manual mentions `control-c` but not `-z` or `-t` which as I mentioned originally are known to exist https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/trmlshtcts/2.12/mac/11.0